# Percentage based android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to wrap my head around android layouts, and I thought I would start with an easy example but it is not working for some reason.

I started by just dividing the layout into 4 blocks, and using background colors to prove it is working as intended.

This code works great for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So I wanted to continue the breakdown of the sections, and add two new layouts over the 2nd one that each fill it 50% (effectively covering it).

I have tried both LinearLayout and RelativeLayout, and I cannot get anything to work.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">
    </RelativeLayout>Layout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I think the issue is with the match_parent in the sub LinearLayouts, but the problem is if I use wrap_content, there is no content so they disappear.

Comment: You should use `android:weightSum` property to parent layouts too.

Comment: Nested weight layouts are discouraged.

Comment: Enter some height to relative layout and add some screen shots of your current layout. Try not to use nested layout.

Answer (score 5):

Please check updated xml. it will work fine

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I have added **weightsum** tags and changed one of your **relative layout to Linear layout**

Comment: Ahhhh, the weightsum makes sense now, I thought it was automatically doing that for Layouts at the same level. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tennesseej   If you think my answer is acceptable and helpful, you can mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

The views inside `RelativeLayout` will have no effect of weight property. You should try to replace `RelativeLayout` with `LinearLayout`.